# Backbone.js Click Event Won't Fire on Previously Added Subviews

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, click, backbone-events

I've been trying to resolve this for days!

The use-case is one that I would think to be very common; I have a button (`<button id="add-item">`) that adds a new item element (`<div class="item">`) to a container element (`<div id="list">`) which in turn should display a form (`<form>`) for the item in a panel (`<div id="panel">`). I want to be able to click on the items and have the panel show the form specific to the item.

**The problem** is that **the only item recognizing a click event is the last item added**; none of the previously added items views will recognize a click.

I had this working before by having a click event on the `List` view on `.item` but was told by a prominent member of the Backbone.js community that the item view really should handle a click itself rather than delegating that responsibility up to it's container.

In order to help you who might be able to help to understand the problem I have created an extremely pared down and self-contained example to illustrate.  You can see it any of these three (3) places:

- [A JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mikeschinkel/TTFA3/1/)
- [A Gist](https://gist.github.com/mikeschinkel/6041295)
- [Our Website](http://newclarity.net/backbonejs/click-event-will-not-fire/)

Also, if you have any suggestions for how to better structure this code I'm 100% enthusiastic to hear them; I'm new to Backbone.js and do not feel I fully understand it's patterns, practices and idioms.

P.S. I've read everything here on StackOverflow that I can find and I can find nothing that addresses the problem so in case you want to close my question as a duplicate please do me the favor and make sure it actually is a duplicate first.

### UPDATE

I'm fixing the code but leaving the errant `this.$el.empty()` commented out so others can who have the same issue can learn from this. Thanks to @sardine/[@tollmaz](http://twitter.com/tolmanz) for helping me out on this over Twitter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per a [Twitter conversation](https://twitter.com/mikeschinkel/status/358313791538208768), it turns out that the issue is with:

```
this.$el.empty();
```

When you create the new item, the events are set up. Upon clicking the item, the `select` method is executed. As part of this method, an instance of `app.ListView` executes its `render` method. Within this method, `$el`, which is actually `#list`, is emptied. As such, the previously created view with working events is nuked. While it is repopulated visually, the event is never recreated (not sure why this is though).